# Adding gaps in between sprite image

Tags: html, css, sprite

I have this image: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160602/xfrddbfa.png

and I would like to add it into my website. But, I'd also like to add a small gap in between each and every flag.

Is that somehow possible? Here is the HTML where I'd like to place it as a pseudo element before the class "headline":

```
<div class="bottom_dual">
    <a title="title" href="#">
        <span class="headline">Lorem ipsum</span>
    </a>
    <span class="caption">Lorem ipsum.</span>
    <span class="more">
        <a class="teaser_link" href="#">more</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The correct answer is to use Photoshop to edit the image. Split it into 5 images, then control the spacing with css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image editing isout of the scope of HTML/CSS and I would really suggest just making separate images using image editing software for each flag if this is what you intend to do, but I will provide an ugly work around if you truly wish to do this.

Also, I'm not sure you're using pseudo element correctly.

Place the image tag 5 times - 1 for each flag.

```
<img id="flag1" src="example.com" />
<img id="flag2" src="example.com" />
<img id="flag3" src="example.com" />
<img id="flag4" src="example.com" />
<img id="flag5" src="example.com" />
```

Use CSS to crop each image to each flag.

```
#flag1{
  position: absolute;
  clip:(rect, 0px, 30px, 20px, 0px); // Position of the flag
}
etc..
```

I hate myself for even giving that answer. Seriously, just edit the image.

Comment: I've used single span elements and gave them different background-positions with margins around. This worked quite well. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem is to use photoshop..

Cut your 5 flags out from that one single image

Then move them (space them )...

Links which You could refer to:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6aMbMk9IGoM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTHudF4fo2I

The above links explain you on how to cut (crop ) an image and to move them..

Hope this helps you..

Comment: I used single elements with background-position. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

use this style :

```
.headline:before{
        padding-left:30px;
        background:url(http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160602/xfrddbfa.png) no-repeat -66px 0px;            
        content:" ";
    }
```